# How to find the confidence level of a classification?

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, random-forest

Say these's a random forest model used to classify 5 different classes. How do we get a confidence level of the prediction?
Say business wants to know what class will happen with high confidence

Comment: check for 'conformal prediction'; see also my answer  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247551/how-to-determine-the-confidence-of-a-neural-network-prediction/247568#247568

Answer (score 0):

Understand *what* you are modeling, talk to domain experts, collect relevant data. Accept that some things simply cannot be predicted with certainty. [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352) Anything more specific will depend on your particular use case.